# Why doesn't Stack Overflow use ObjectURL / BLOB to temporarily store images?

Tags: discussion, questions, design, images

I just read about [BLOBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) in JavaScript, and how they could be used to show the image which has been uploaded. Here's the code which should do the the job:

#### HTML

```
<input type='file' id='foo'>
Selected Image : <img id='photo'>
```

#### JavaScript

```
 var fileData = document.getElementById('foo').files[0];
 var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
 var imageUrl = url.createObjectURL(fileData);
 document.getElementById('photo').src=imageUrl;
```

This solution temporarily shows the image which has been uploaded, without actually storing the image in the server. In the case of Stack Overflow, when you create a new question, and you upload an image, it saves it directly onto a server, and generates a URL, similar to this one:

---

---

[image]

Now, as I deleted the question, I really never needed the image, and I removed the URL. But even then, the image is on the server and can be accessed by anyone by using the URL.

Shouldn't the method above or a similar one be used to display the image while the user is typing the question be adopted, and the images should only be saved when the user actually posts the question? It would surely save some memory.

Comment: I'd suspect they'll have script running regularly, cleaning this up.

Comment: As you can see from the URL, the images are uploaded to an external service. If I were running Stack Overflow I wouldn't spend any resources trying to micro-optimize some other company's server.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ We can't be sure. And I think this would be better, as it would take no memory at all. And also, to check if the image is being used somewhere and is just not a "waste-link" would take up huge amount of processes.

Comment: What's up with the downvotes?

Comment: This looks like it would be pure busywork with near zero benefit. You'd be investing a load of effort (that has to be tested on a lot of platforms, etc.) for what benefit exactly? To save imgur's servers a few kilobytes? They had [4 *Petabytes* of traffic each month three years ago.](https://www.reddit.com/r/iama/comments/y81ju/) Plus it would take away from the an easy way to occasionally misuse SO/imgur to host an image I need to share.

Comment: Here is some related discussion in the blog post announcing the imgur upload feature: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, It doesn't get cleaned up ever. Images from 5 years ago are still intact and will remain so into the future.

Answer (score 9):

A few reasons not to implement this:

1. Busy work for developers, with no benefit to Stack Exchange.
2. User would no longer see the actual source of the post they are about to submit.
3. Imgur offers image resizing that works by appending a letter to the filename. Users wouldn't be able to take advantage of that at the time of posting.
4. Users would no longer be able to use the answer box to upload an image just to include it as a link in a *comment*. This is a rare use case, but a legitimate one: one can try to clarify the problem a user is having by commenting with "[this is how that page looks for me](image link)", etc.

Honestly, reason 1 should be enough.

Comment: Actually, option 4 (using the service as a free image host) isn't officially encouraged is it?

Comment: @Pacerier That's not what #4 is talking about, it's for internal consumption.

Comment: @brasofilo, I remembered reading (don't have the link) that that's discouraged . But are you saying that as long as the images are linked from a comment posted in SE it's officially greenlighted? or not?

Comment: @Pacerier: I won't say it's "officially greenlighted" because I don't have a link to back it up right now. But, personally, as long it is Stack related I don't have any issues uploading, using, sharing or linking images at stack.imgur account. It is not as if we were uploading our high-res 500+ vacation's photos...

Comment: @brasofilo, folks at http://photo.stackexchange.com/